# Golang library not check "psk_ke" value in PskKeyExchangeModes when receive a ClientHello message in TLS 1.3

Tags: tls-psk

I use Golang code at 1.21.0 version, and I have some concern about **TLS 1.3** library source code.
As I know, at chapter "*4.2.9.Pre-Shared Key Exchange Modes*" of **RFC 8446** have mention about PskKeyExchangeModes.
The **PskKeyExchangeModes** have 2 value psk_ke(0) and psk_dhe_ke(1) same at picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y3wj.png)

I understand it as follows:

- In the first handshake: The client send ClientHello message to the server, and this ClientHello message has an PskKeyExchangeModes extension with psk_dhe_ke(1) value so that inform to server that PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment.The Server after receive this message will reply to client a Session ticket message.
- In the second handshake(resumption handshake) The client send ClientHello message has an PskKeyExchangeModes extension with psk_ke(0) value so that inform to server that PSK-only key establishment. In this case the server no need send  a "key_share" value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7RO3.png)

but in Golang code(version 1.21.0) library always check the psk_dhe_ke(1) and **return nil** if value difference psk_dhe_ke(1)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9MPF.png)

I don't know why they do that. is there something wrong ?
Please let me know.

I expect any answer